# Spring Boot Admin many logins to secured Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Is it a normal behavior that Spring Boot Admin sends a ton of logins to actuator endpoint if that is secured with basic auth?

I see several logins per second when spring boot admin is open in the audit menu

**Spring Boot Admin Server** (Just a basic setup with login details in application.properties)

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=XXXX
```

**Spring Boot Admin Client**

```
spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.password=XXXX
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.name=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.password=XXXX
```

and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
http.csrf().disable();
http.antMatcher("/actuator/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("monitoring").and().httpBasic();
```

As soon as I open the admin UI and click on the registered instance where all the endpoints are queried I see a lot of logins from admin in audit view up to 2-20 per second. When I open and refresh endpoints in browser I see only a single login.

Is there some bad configuration on either side?

Comment: What do you mean by *I see several logins*. AFAIK there is no dedicated logiin endpoint. What requests do you see? What URL is called?

Comment: the actuator endpoint is called with basic auth i believe. i am not sure if basic auth can be somehow stored in a session or something, but it seems that every request from admin to every endpoint is logged into the audit logs